# CPU spikes to 30% when watching any kind of videos in exodia os (arch distro)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, video, gpu, cpu-usage

Recently i switched from windows to Linux.

I've been trying a lot of distros, but my choice fell on exodia (arch distro based on bspwm). I find it really useful for me as someone who is into programming. I am enjoying everything except one thing. When I was on Windows this wasn't the case there. But when I changed my OS my CPU load is really unstable all the time, especially when watching any kind of videos. The CPU usage on Windows was around 4%-10% all the time, but here in exodia its 0% when nothing is spun up, but as soon as i start even using my mouse or moreover watching YouTube videos, my CPU goes straight to 30% and then as the video loads it drops to 20% + additionally my laptop temp rises to 75 Celsius which makes my fans go crazy.

I thought that the problem is with my drivers. I got NVIDIA Geforce 1650. I tried installing some proprietary ones but once I rebooted my PC, it fails to boot all the time, I guess the conflict with GPU drivers appear and the only way i can log in and launch my OS is to change my settings to NOMODESET. (I checked and there's actually nvidia-settings installed and I found out that when watching videos my GPU only uses 10% of its memory, therefore CPU takes almost all the rendering, correct me if I'm wrong).

I also tried enabling hardware acceleration in Chrome and Firefox but to no avail.

Comment: `nomodeset`disables any graphics drivers other than a generic one that always works. You really need to install the correct Nvidia drivers version and sign them if using Secure Boot. That's all.

Comment: Would be great if you respected English spelling and grammar next time. I've fixed literally three dozen errors in your post.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov i gotcha but what do u suggest to fix my issue

Comment: Install Ubuntu and proprietary NVIDIA drivers using the official installation method. No need to hop between distros and trying distros for IT pros, like Arch Linux. 22.04 LTS should work fine for you. Actually I'd stay with Windows if I were you. Linux support for switchable graphics has not been very good.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thx, appreciate it.

Comment: @Tom it makes sense to post your question here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148 It's NVIDIA's primary Linux support website.